# Recover Mysql data from formated hard disk

Tags: mysql, recovery, disaster-recovery

One of my machine got crashed last day and i ended up reinstalling windows on that machine. It had a mysql server in it. Is there a way to recover mysql data from that machine now . There are couple of tables which has some important data for which backup was not there.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't have done anything after the crash. If you formatted the disk and reinstalled windows, they're most likely gone for good.

Comment: If the volume where MySQL databases were stored was formatted during re-install process, all data is lost with a guarantee. If this volume was not re-formatted, there is a (extremely) minor probability  to recover raw datafiles using any euristic recovery software (moreover, recovered datafiles may contain wrong data). So I think you may forget about those data.

Answer (score 2):

Before you do anything make sure nothing can overwrite data on the disk. stop all writes to the disk ASAP. Unmount, take it out of a server - whatever is applicable and feasible. Plug the disk in a 64bit Linux machine.

Then you need to take an image from this disk. I prefer `dd` for the job. It's available everywhere, stores the image as it is.

```
 dd if=/dev/sdb of=/path/on/sda/faulty_disk.img  conv=noerror
```

Where `/dev/sdb` is the disk with data and `/path/on/sda/faulty_disk.img` is a path on another disk, big enough to store the image. `conv=noerror` will ignore disk read errors if you get any.

If you prefer to store the image remotely - check out https://twindb.com/take-image-from-corrupted-hard-drive/ , it describes more options.

Then download and compile [Undrop-for-InnoDB](https://twindb.com/data-recovery-toolkit/).
Then follow steps from [tutorial](https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/):

You need to find InnoDB pages on the image. The `stream_parser`tool does it:

```
./stream_parser -f /path/on/sda/faulty_disk.img
```

The result of the tool will be a directory `pages-faulty_disk.img` that contains InnoDB pages sorted by page type and index_id. InnoDB stores tables in indexes. The table itself is stored in the `PRIMARY` index, secondary indexes are stored separately. To recover the data we need to fetch records from PRIMARY indexes. Now, InnoDB identifies indexes by `index_id` while we, humans, know table names. To find index_id for each table you will need to [restore InnoDB dictionary first](https://twindb.com/how-to-recover-innodb-dictionary/). You can check the blog post or script `recover_dictionary.sh` from the undrop-for-innodb toolkit.

Now, let's say you found index_id for each table and there is a respective index file in `pages-faulty_disk.img/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/<index_id>.page`.

To extract records from the index you need to know the table schema, because InnoDB doesn't store the schema in the index. I hope you have the schema either from old backups, or maybe from the installation script. Worst case you can try to [restore the schema from InnoDB dictionary](https://twindb.com/recover-table-structure-from-innodb-dictionary/).

When you have the schema and index_id you can generate text dumps from the index.

```
./c_parser -6f pages-faulty_disk.img/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/0000000000000015.page -t sakila/actor.sql > dumps/default/actor 2> dumps/default/actor_load.sql
```

Obviously, `sakila`.`actor` is just an example.
Then review the text dump `dumps/default/actor` and you can load it with an SQL command stored in `dumps/default/actor.sql`.
[The tool's page](https://twindb.com/data-recovery-toolkit/) also refers to some other tutorials which may be useful. Data recovery is quite unpredictable so you have to get familiar with the tool and process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does it matters that the computer in the OP's question was running Windows?

Comment: It doesn’t because Innodb tablespaces binary compatible across all platforms